# Terminal.app Macintosh

Tags: macos, terminal

Terminal.app Macintosh MacOS 10.13.x

I am look for some select not all file name.
Example: 
ls -l apple*
ls: apple*: No such file or directory

I am focus apple* . . . not other name file.

Look list:

Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot.ttf

Apple Braille Outline 8 Dot.ttf

Apple Braille Pinpoint 6 Dot.ttf

Apple Braille Pinpoint 8 Dot.ttf

Apple Braille.ttf

Apple Color Emoji.ttc

Apple Symbols.ttf

AppleSDGothicNeo.ttc

AquaKana.ttc

ArabicUIDisplay.ttc

ArabicUIText.ttc

ArialHB.ttc

Avenir Next Condensed.ttc

Avenir Next.ttc

Avenir.ttc

Courier.dfont

GeezaPro.ttc

Geneva.dfont

HelveLTMM

Helvetica.ttc

HelveticaNeue.ttc

HelveticaNeueDeskInterface.ttc

Hiragino Sans GB.ttc

Keyboard.ttf

Kohinoor.ttc

Answer (score 0):

The bash shell treats filenames as case-sensitive.

The filenames begin with `Apple` (with a capital `A`), not `apple`.

Comment: It work for now thank you for explain me about follow CAP and lower letter exactly I got it.